# Lost in CUDA device pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, cuda

As part of my thesis work I am working in a CUDA project (modifying somebody elses code, adding functionality, etc). Being new to CUDA this is turning to be a real challenge for me. I am working with **compute capability 1.3** cards, 4 x Tesla C1060. And sadly, I am hitting some limitations of the platform.

I need to pass a couple of new structures to device, which I believe are been copied correctly. But, when trying to pass the pointers to structure on device on my kernel call I reach the 256 bytes limit (as addressed in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895167/ideas-for-cuda-kernel-calls-with-parameters-exceeding-256-bytes)).

My code goes like this:

```
// main.cu
static void RunGPU(HostThreadState *hstate)
{
  SimState *HostMem = &(hstate->host_sim_state);
  SimState DeviceMem;

  TetrahedronStructGPU *h_root = &(hstate->root);
  TetrahedronStructGPU *d_root;
  TriangleFacesGPU *h_faces = &(hstate->faces);
  TriangleFacesGPU *d_faces;

  GPUThreadStates tstates;

  unsigned int n_threads = hstate->n_tblks * NUM_THREADS_PER_BLOCK;
  unsigned int n_tetras  = hstate->n_tetras; // 9600
  unsigned int n_faces   = hstate->n_faces;  // 38400

  InitGPUStates(HostMem, h_root, h_faces, &DeviceMem, &tstates, hstate->sim, 
                d_root, d_faces, n_threads, n_tetras, n_faces );
  cudaThreadSynchronize();

  ...

  kernel<<<dimGrid, dimBlock, k_smem_sz>>>(DeviceMem, tstates, /*OK, these 2*/
                                           d_root, d_faces);
                           // Limit of 256 bytes adding d_root and/or d_faces
  cudaThreadSynchronize();

  ...

}
```

The `InitGPUStates` function is in another source file:

```
// kernel.cu
int InitGPUStates(SimState* HostMem, TetrahedronStructGPU* h_root,
                  TriangleFacesGPU* h_faces,
                  SimState* DeviceMem, GPUThreadStates *tstates,
                  SimulationStruct* sim, 
                  TetrahedronStructGPU* d_root, TriangleFacesGPU* d_faces,
                  int n_threads, int n_tetras, int n_faces)
{
  unsigned int size;

  // Allocate and copy RootTetrahedron (d_root) on device
  size = n_tetras * sizeof(TetrahedronStructGPU); // Too big
  checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_root, size));
  checkCudaErrors(cudaMemcpy(d_root, h_root, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

  // Allocate and copy Faces (d_faces) on device
  size = n_faces * sizeof(TriangleFacesGPU); // Too big
  checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_faces, size));
  checkCudaErrors(cudaMemcpy(d_faces, h_faces, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));     

  ...
}
```

I understand that I need to pass only pointers to the locations on device memory. How can I get the address in device? Is this passing of pointers correctly done?

The two new structures are:

```
// header.h
typedef struct {
  int idx;
  int vertices[4];
  float Nx, Ny, Nz, d;
} TriangleFacesGPU;

typedef struct {
  int idx, region;
  int vertices[4], faces[4], adjTetras[4];
  float n, mua, mus, g;
} TetrahedronStructGPU;

// other structures
typedef struct {
  BOOLEAN *is_active;
  BOOLEAN *dead;
  BOOLEAN *FstBackReflectionFlag;
  int *NextTetrahedron;
  UINT32 *NumForwardScatters;
  UINT32 *NumBackwardScatters;
  UINT32 *NumBackwardsSpecularReflections;
  UINT32 *NumBiases;
  UINT32 *p_layer;
  GFLOAT *p_x, *p_y, *p_z;
  GFLOAT *p_ux, *p_uy, *p_uz;
  GFLOAT *p_w;
  GFLOAT *Rspecular;
  GFLOAT *LocationFstBias;
  GFLOAT *OpticalPath;
  GFLOAT *MaxDepth;
  GFLOAT *MaxLikelihoodRatioIncrease;
  GFLOAT *LikelihoodRatioIncreaseFstBias;
  GFLOAT *LikelihoodRatio;
  GFLOAT *LikelihoodRatioAfterFstBias;
  GFLOAT *s, *sleft;
  TetrahedronStructGPU *tetrahedron;
  TriangleFacesGPU *faces;
} GPUThreadStates;

typedef struct {
  UINT32 *n_p_left;
  UINT64 *x;
  UINT32 *a;
  UINT64 *Rd_ra;
  UINT64 *A_rz;
  UINT64 *Tt_ra;
} SimState;
```

The definition of `kernel` is

```
__global__ void kernel(SimState d_state, GPUThreadStates tstates,
                       TetrahedronStructGPU *d_root,
                       TriangleFacesGPU *d_faces);
```

I will work on changing `SimState d_state` to pointer pass `SimState *d_state`. As well as `GPUThreadStates tstates` to `GPUThreadStates *tstates`.

Comment: what is the declaration of `kernel`?  For example you appear to be passing `tstates` *by value* to `kernel`.  If `sizeof(GPUThreadStates)` is large, you can free up some breathing room by passing that structure by pointer rather than by value.  The problem is, `d_root` and `d_faces` are *already* pointers.  So if you're out of parameter space just adding those two pointers, you're going to need to shrink the size of something else you are passing, like `DeviceMem` (`sizeof(SimState)`) and `tstates` (`sizeof(GPUThreadStates)`).  This will also affect your kernel code referencing these entities.

Comment: @RobertCrovella You are right. I wasn't sure I was doing the pointer passing properly. The kernel definition `__global__ void MCMLKernel(SimState d_state, GPUThreadStates tstates, TetrahedronStructGPU *d_root, TriangleFacesGPU *d_faces)` and both `d_state` and `tstates` are being passed by value, aren't they?

Comment: Yes, they appear to be, although you haven't actually shown the definition of `GPUThreadStates` and `SimState`.  If the sizes of those are large, preventing you from adding `d_root` (a pointer) and `d_faces` (a pointer), then you will have to focus on those.

Comment: @RobertCrovella Thanks again. I am working on those, `GPUThreadStates` and `SimState` are quite big too. I am adding those definitions above.

Comment: @RobertCrovella I posted the modifications I made as an answer for better formatting. I am having errors `code=11(cudaErrorInvalidValue) "cudaMalloc((void**)&DeviceMem->n_photons_left, size)" `. I would really appreciate your help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, solved the 256 bytes issue. But, really still lost in pointers

My modified code goes like this:

```
// main.cu
static void RunGPU(HostThreadState *hstate)
{
  SimState *HostMem = &(hstate->host_sim_state);

  // new pointers to pass
  SimState *DeviceMem = (SimState*)malloc(sizeof(SimState));
  GPUThreadStates *tstates = (GPUThreadStates*)malloc(sizeof(GPUThreadStates));

  TetrahedronStructGPU *h_root = hstate->root; //root, pointer in HostThreadState
  TetrahedronStructGPU *d_root;
  TriangleFacesGPU *h_faces = hstate->faces; //faces, pointer in HostThreadState
  TriangleFacesGPU *d_faces;

  unsigned int n_threads = hstate->n_tblks * NUM_THREADS_PER_BLOCK;
  unsigned int n_tetras  = hstate->n_tetras; // 9600
  unsigned int n_faces   = hstate->n_faces;  // 38400

  InitGPUStates(HostMem, h_root, h_faces, DeviceMem, tstates, hstate->sim, 
                d_root, d_faces, n_threads, n_tetras, n_faces );
  cudaThreadSynchronize();

  ...

  kernel<<<dimGrid, dimBlock, k_smem_sz>>>(DeviceMem, tstates,
                                           d_root, d_faces);
                                         // No limit reached!
  cudaThreadSynchronize();

  ...      
}
```

In the `InitGPUStates` function the changes are as follow. Special attention to the copy of DeviceMem (I tried many forms without success). Some forms (with parenthesis, like this `cudaMalloc((void **)&(*DeviceMem).n_p_left, size)`) will not give me any error. I am assuming that no errors means no data copied to device. In the current form the error is `code=11(cudaErrorInvalidValue) "cudaMalloc((void**)&DeviceMem->n_photons_left, size)"`.

```
// kernel.cu
int InitGPUStates(SimState* HostMem, TetrahedronStructGPU* h_root,
                  TriangleFacesGPU* h_faces,
                  SimState* DeviceMem, GPUThreadStates *tstates,
                  SimulationStruct* sim, 
                  TetrahedronStructGPU* d_root, TriangleFacesGPU* d_faces,
                  int n_threads, int n_tetras, int n_faces)
{
  unsigned int size;

  // Allocate and copy RootTetrahedron (d_root) on device
  size = n_tetras * sizeof(TetrahedronStructGPU); // Too big
  checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_root, size));
  checkCudaErrors(cudaMemcpy(d_root, h_root, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

  // Allocate and copy Faces (d_faces) on device
  size = n_faces * sizeof(TriangleFacesGPU); // Too big
  checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_faces, size));
  checkCudaErrors(cudaMemcpy(d_faces, h_faces, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));     

  // HELP NEEDED MAINLY FROM HERE REGARDING POINTER VALUE COPY!
  checkCudaErrors( cudaMalloc((void**)&DeviceMem, sizeof(SimState) ); //Needed?

  size = sizeof(UINT32);
  checkCudaErrors( cudaMalloc(&DeviceMem->n_p_left, size) );
  checkCudaErrors( cudaMemcpy(DeviceMem->n_p_left,
                   HostMem->n_p_left, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice) );

  size = n_threads * sizeof(UINT32);
  checkCudaErrors( cudaMalloc(&DeviceMem->a, size) );
  checkCudaErrors( cudaMemcpy(DeviceMem->a, HostMem->a, size,
                                      cudaMemcpyHostToDevice) );
  size = n_threads * sizeof(UINT64);
  checkCudaErrors( cudaMalloc(&DeviceMem->x, size) );
  checkCudaErrors( cudaMemcpy(DeviceMem->x, HostMem->x, size,
                                      cudaMemcpyHostToDevice) );
  ...
}
```

I understand that I need to pass only pointers to the locations on device memory. How can I get the address in device? Is this passing of pointers correctly done?

The two new structures are:

```
// header.h
typedef struct {
  int idx;
  int vertices[4];
  float Nx, Ny, Nz, d;
} TriangleFacesGPU;

typedef struct {
  int idx, region;
  int vertices[4], faces[4], adjTetras[4];
  float n, mua, mus, g;
} TetrahedronStructGPU;

// other structures
typedef struct {
  BOOLEAN *is_active;
  BOOLEAN *dead;
  BOOLEAN *FstBackReflectionFlag;
  int *NextTetrahedron;
  UINT32 *NumForwardScatters;
  UINT32 *NumBackwardScatters;
  UINT32 *NumBackwardsSpecularReflections;
  UINT32 *NumBiases;
  UINT32 *p_layer;
  GFLOAT *p_x, *p_y, *p_z;
  GFLOAT *p_ux, *p_uy, *p_uz;
  GFLOAT *p_w;
  GFLOAT *Rspecular;
  GFLOAT *LocationFstBias;
  GFLOAT *OpticalPath;
  GFLOAT *MaxDepth;
  GFLOAT *MaxLikelihoodRatioIncrease;
  GFLOAT *LikelihoodRatioIncreaseFstBias;
  GFLOAT *LikelihoodRatio;
  GFLOAT *LikelihoodRatioAfterFstBias;
  GFLOAT *s, *sleft;
  TetrahedronStructGPU *tetrahedron;
  TriangleFacesGPU *faces;
} GPUThreadStates;

typedef struct {
  UINT32 *n_p_left;
  UINT64 *x;
  UINT32 *a;
  UINT64 *Rd_ra;
  UINT64 *A_rz;
  UINT64 *Tt_ra;
} SimState;
```

The definition of `kernel` is changed to:

```
__global__ void kernel(SimState *d_state, GPUThreadStates *tstates,
                       TetrahedronStructGPU *d_root,
                       TriangleFacesGPU *d_faces);
```

Comment: Should it not be something like `cudaMalloc((void**)&(DeviceMem->n_p_left), size)` ?

Comment: @Ashalynd I tried. Still getting the same error code=11(cudaErrorInvalidValue)

Comment: there is already a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19404965/how-to-use-cudamalloc-cudamemcpy-for-a-pointer-to-a-structure-containing-point (And it looks like you don't need to cast your pointer to void**)

Comment: Ah, there is something else. Your InitGPUStates function should receive a pointer to your DeviceMem and then give that pointer to the cudaMalloc. And you forgot to initialize DeviceMem structure :)

Comment: @Ashalynd by initialize `DeviceMem` you mean `cudaMalloc` as in your answer? I know there is a question about void** around, gonna re-read the answers better to understand better the [need of void**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12936986/why-does-cudamalloc-use-pointer-to-pointer) in the first place. Thanks! I am checking the [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19404965/how-to-use-cudamalloc-cudamemcpy-for-a-pointer-to-a-structure-containing-point) as well.

Comment: Basically I mean that you have declared DeviceMem as a pointer-to-struct, but the struct itself was not allocated (at least I didn't see it in provided code snippets). That is probably the reason why you were getting these errors, because the pointer was pointing to garbage.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you haven't initialized the DeviceMem structure, which is supposed to hold the pointer that should be later initialized with cudaMalloc.

You should do something like:

```
SimState* DeviceMem;

cudaMalloc(&DeviceMem, sizeof(SimState))
```

too (or any other way to allocate memory for that pointer).

Comment: It does not matter that I am allocating each element in the `SimState` structure by itself? I didn't include that code, only the first three elements `DeviceMem->n_p_left`, `DeviceMem->a`, and `DeviceMem->x`. But, I do the same for the following elements as well (`Rd_ra`, `A_rz`, and `Tt_ra`).

Comment: Since I am passing `DeviceMem` by reference (not value as before) in the `kernel` call, I might need to allocate the complete structure as mentioned. But, not 100% sure. The thing is that the debugging capability on the GPU is so limited (maybe I'm not finding the correct way yet). I find it difficult to track my data once on the device.

Comment: Well, strictly speaking it's not "passing by reference". You are passing by pointer. If you were passing by reference, your object would have already existed and you'd been using a reference to it as a function argument, e.g. `void f(int& i)` - here `i`, the function argument, is passed as a reference. But it's only possible in C++, not in pure C.

Comment: @kronos @t_carn In the [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19404965/how-to-use-cudamalloc-cudamemcpy-for-a-pointer-to-a-structure-containing-point). How do you make your kernel call `doThings`? Do you pass the pointer to structure `Matrix` as a whole or to `Matrix.elements` individually?

Comment: As far as I can see, they allocate the array of Matrix structures by the regular malloc, and then pass the data members of these structures to the CUDA functions.

Comment: You are right. I tried without the casting the pointer to void** and I am not getting the error anymore... Also, I am doing `cudaMalloc((void**)&DeviceMem, sizeof(SimState))`. I am thinking that in individual elements of the structure I don't need the casting since I'am referencing to a pointer in that structure. But, for `DeviceMem` I still need to use void**.